# The best way to reduce quantity of colors in bitmap palette

Tags: c#, wpf, bitmap

I have a bitmap which contains a lot of different colors. But I need to make a scheme from this image with 40 colors or less. That's why I need method to reduce quantity of colors in the bitmap palette.

I'm using code below for my app:

```
        using System.Windows.Media.Imaging; //BitmapSource

        ==================================================

        //Create palette of requied color. Pay heed to maxColorCount it 
        //can have any value, but PixelFormats supports only 2,4,16 and 256 colors.
        var myPalette = new BitmapPalette(ConvertBitmap(b) as BitmapSource, 16);

        newFormatedBitmapSource.DestinationPalette = myPalette;

        //Set PixelFormats
        newFormatedBitmapSource.DestinationFormat = PixelFormats.Indexed8;
        newFormatedBitmapSource.EndInit();

        b = BitmapFromSource(newFormatedBitmapSource);
```

It works, but very often as a result I recieve an image with bright pixels on a mostly solid background of darker colours:

[image]
[image]

I tried to do it by myself: get nearest 4 or 9 pixels (square) & blend it. Also I tried to reduce bitmap size and "stretch" the bitmap. In the end I was trying to absorb nearest colors. But the best result I got using method above.

**That's why I'm looking for better way to reduce quantity of colors in bitmap palette.**

P.S. Images were scaled, and I also drew a grid on top of them.

**UPDATED:**

I tried to use **scolorq**, but result was the same. Question still relevant.

Comment: and your question is?

Comment: I'm looking for better way to reduce quantity of colors in bitmap palette

Comment: what research have you done? there are a lot of resources out there on how to do that.

Comment: I tried to do it by myself: get nearest 4 or 9 pixels (square) & blend it. Also I tried to reduce bitmap size and "stretch" the bitmap. But the best result I got using method above.

Comment: In the end I was trying to absorb nearest colors.

Comment: A very good utility is the scolorq: A Spatial Color Quantization Utility. The site has a source code(in c++ of cource for speed). More more details [scolorq: A Spatial Color Quantization Utility](http://www.cs.berkeley.edu/~dcoetzee/downloads/scolorq/#sampleimages).

Comment: valter, thanks a lot for your comment, but it looks like scolorq gives the same result as the wpf function above :( But I'll check it out as soon as I can.

Comment: Native code that implements this algorithm can be found here: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1433/CQuantizer Try it with your images. You can use it as is using ,NET-native interop, or rewrite in C#.

Comment: thanks for your comment, Alex. I'll try it as soon as I can

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A great app with source code in C# is available [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/66341/A-Simple-Yet-Quite-Powerful-Palette-Quantizer-in-C). It implements 8 algorithms and has tons of options.